# Is there a Windows solution for a program that relies on netrc?

Tags: windows, credentials

I have a Perl script that works well on Windows, however one function requires the use of a `.netrc` file for retrieving credentials.

Is there a Windows equivalent of `.netrc`,  or other solution, on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows should be identical, except for the fact that your home directory is in a different location.

Try looking in the `%userprofile%` directory for `.netrc`.

If it's missing you can create it in Explorer by creating a new file named `.netrc.` (the final `.` will disappear).

You [may need to](http://nick.txtcc.com/index.php/other/983) create an environmental variable named `HOME` that points to `%USERPROFILE%`, like so: `setx HOME %USERPROFILE%`

Comment: `.netrc` by default doesn't exist under Windows, and would need to be created especially for this script. Putting it in `%userprofile%` would fail to live up to the Windows convention, which has per-user configuration files in `c:\Users\<Username>\AppData\...`. See my answer for more.

Comment: I actually tried to create one, but it's not a valid filename.

Comment: you actually can have a file named that... windows is just dumb and thinks the .netrc is the extension without a filename.  Try naming the file ".netrc." (with a dot at the end as well as the beginning)

Comment: @AaronMiller: It's not supposed to live up to the Windows convention anyway; the function that looks for `~/.netrc` was just imported from Unix. (Windows has a completely different credential storage mechanism anyway.) And no, such files don't exist by default on Unix either.

Comment: @Louis: Either create it via command line (e.g. `copy nul .netrc`) or by entering the name *with double quotes* (`".netrc"`) in Notepad's "Save" dialog.

Comment: The trailing `.` did the trick!

Comment: @grawity The reason I mention living up to the Windows convention is that there are some instances in which not doing so can be harmful, as for example when using the ComboFix tool to clean up a malware infestation -- older versions, at least, and perhaps the current version as well, will blow away anything in %userprofile% that wasn't created by the system, on the assumption that it might be malware. Whether it's a concern in any given circumstance is an open question, but it's definitely worth considering in light of the potential drawbacks.

Comment: @Aaron: How does it even *know* what was created by the system? I noticed that Windows 7 has made the profile directory much more visible in the GUI than previously (it became similar to a "home" directory), so I imagine many people would create their own files there...

Comment: @grawity It doesn't *know* so much as it *guesses*, and assumes anything it doesn't recognize is necessarily hostile -- perhaps not all that unreasonable given that it's intended to be run on a potentially quite badly infected machine, and that user- or program-created files in `%userprofile%` aren't actually all that common. Generally, it seems that Windows users are expected to use the Documents, Downloads, My Pictures/Music/&c. folders, rather than the profile root itself, even under Windows 7. (I also haven't run ComboFix on a Windows 7 box; it may behave differently there.)

Comment: Or the filename should be `_netrc`?

Answer (score 1):

On **Windows OS** open `cmd.exe`, type

```
echo %HOME%
```

and then

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

Output should be the same. If not do this

```
setx HOME %USERPROFILE%
```

Afterwards create **`_netrc`** file inside `%USERPROFILE%` directory and add

```
machine <hostname1>
login <login1>
password <password1>
```

Example [here](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/1072829)

> **Important!** on Windows you should create **`_netrc`** instead of **`.netrc`**

More on this you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for whether you're running on Windows, and if so, inquire of a separate configuration file, rather than looking for `.netrc`:

```
my $config_file = '';
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
  $config_file = 'c:\\path\\to\\config.ini';
}
else {
  $config_file = '~/.netrc';
};
```

The `.netrc` file by default lives in a user's `$HOME`, whose equivalent on the Windows platform is `c:\{Users|Documents and Settings}\<Username>` -- 'Users' for Windows Vista and newer, 'Documents and Settings' for XP and older. You could create a `.netrc` file there and populate it with the necessary credentials, which would require fewer (or no) changes in your code -- however, it fails to live up to Windows' conventions, which would have configuration files in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\<Developer>\<Program>\` or similar. It's up to you whether you'd rather modify your code to meet the convention, or just look in the user profile base directory for convenience.

Of course, if you're running the script under Cygwin Perl, you can just create `~/.netrc` for the user account, populate it, and have done.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it's not my script (and it's over 600KB in size).

Comment: Well, in that case, you may find it simplest just to create a correctly formatted `.netrc` in `C:\Users\<Username>`, and see if the script can find it from there. If it doesn't, you'll probably need to dig into the code to find out where and how it's looking for the file, and either modify it to do something more sensible or put the `.netrc` file wherever the script expects to find it.

Comment: Or the filename should be `_netrc`?